# Vuetify Radio Buttons with v-for and vuex store not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I am able to update my vuex store just fine, but for some reason I am also able to select all of the radio buttons. Like this:

[image]

How can I make the radio buttons work as they should, and only select one?

```
  <v-radio-group
    v-for="(rates, index) in rateTypes"
    :key="index + 'rates'"
    :class="index > 0 ? 'mt-n2' : ''"
    v-model="country[`${rates.type}`]"
  >
    <v-radio
      :class="index > 0 ? 'mt-n10' : ''"
      color="#68007d"
      value="true"
      :key="index + 'box'"
    >
      <template v-slot:label>
        <p
          class="subtitle-1 black--text mt-4"
        >{{ rates.title }}<strong>{{ rates.price }}</strong></p>
      </template>
    </v-radio>
  </v-radio-group>
```

`rateTypes` is just an array in my `data`

```
  rateTypes: [
    {
      title: "Offer both live Amazon rates, and your own fixed shipping rates - ",
      price: "$40/month",
      type: "manual_and_realtime_country"
    },
    {
      title: "Offer only live Amazon shipping rates - ",
      price: "$35/month",
      type: "realtime_country"
    },
    {
      title: "Offer only your own fixed shipping rates - ",
      price: "$25/month",
      type: "manual_country"
    },
  ],
```

And then `country` is coming from the vuex store and a `v-for`. It looks like this:

```
[{:id=>5,
  :country=>"Canada",
  :charge_id=>nil,
  :shop_id=>1,
  :version_one_country=>false,
  :realtime_country=>"true",
  :manual_country=>"true",
  :manual_and_realtime_country=>"true",    
  :external_order_country=>false,
  :blank_box_country=>false,
  :non_amazon_fulfillment_country=>false,  
  :total_price=>105,
  :paid=>false,
  :created_at=>"2022-04-29T22:34:45.088Z", 
  :updated_at=>"2022-05-01T15:27:58.101Z"},
 {:id=>4,
  :country=>"USA",
  :charge_id=>nil,
  :shop_id=>1,
  :version_one_country=>true,
  :realtime_country=>true,
  :manual_country=>false,
  :manual_and_realtime_country=>true,
  :external_order_country=>false,
  :blank_box_country=>false,
  :non_amazon_fulfillment_country=>false,
  :total_price=>70,
  :paid=>false,
  :created_at=>"2022-04-29T18:57:15.533Z",
  :updated_at=>"2022-05-01T15:57:52.389Z"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code I would guess that you have 3 groups with 1 radio button each instead of one group with 3 buttons. Only buttons inside the same group can have a shared state. Your `v-for="(rates, index) in rateTypes"` should be inside the v-radio

```
<v-radio-group v-model="radioGroupModel">
    <v-radio
      v-for="(rates, index) in rateTypes"
      :class="index > 0 ? 'mt-n10' : ''"
      color="#68007d"
      value="true"
      :key="index + 'box'"
    >
      <template v-slot:label>
        <p
          class="subtitle-1 black--text mt-4"
        >{{ rates.title }}<strong>{{ rates.price }}</strong></p>
      </template>
    </v-radio>
  </v-radio-group>
```

Or something like that. Also see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/radio-buttons/#usage